# Check for a valid date

Tags: c#, date, datetime

So I'm trying to figure out if there is another kind of way to check if a date is valid. So the idea is that if the date is valid then it continue's using the given date, if the date is invalid is uses the date of today.

This is what I got at the moment:

```
        public void setBirthdate(int year, int month, int day)
        {
        if (month < 1 || month > 12 || day < 1 || day > DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
        {
            Birthdate = DateTime.Today;
        }
        else
            Birthdate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
```

So is there any shorter/more readable way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at `TryParseExact` method.

Comment: use `try{Birthdate  = new DateTime(year, month, day); } catch{Birthdate = DateTime.Today;}`

Comment: Where do the numbers for year, month, day come from in the first place? If you've parsed them out of a string, then `DateTime.TryParse` while they are still in one string might be preferable, but otherwise you have the shortest code. If you put a comment in saying "check date is valid, else use the current date" then it will be more readable. You *should* check values in code rather than using exceptions, where possible.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The (string) values come from the constructor when making a new object from this class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could* use the values to try constructing a valid `DateTime`, then catch the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` that occurs if the arguments are out of range:

```
public void setBirthdate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    try
    {
        Birthdate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        Birthdate = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

Some may disagree with using exceptions like this, but I'm just letting the `DateTime` class do its own checks, instead of recreating them myself.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx), an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` occurs if:

- Year is less than 1 or greater than 9999, or
- Month is less than 1 or greater than 12, or
- Day is less than 1 or greater than the number of days in month.

Alternatively, you could copy the logic from the `DateTime` class: *([reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,891f8af5025ab2f3))*

```
public void setBirthdate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && month >= 1 && month <= 12)
    {
        int[] days = DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)
            ? new[] { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365}
            : new[] { 0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366};

        if (day >= 1 && day <= days[month] - days[month - 1])
            Birthdate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
    else
        Birthdate = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Comment: I agree. Exception handling has overhead but you should always leverage your chosen framework. The likelihood that it handles edge cases you haven't considered is high. You can always do further processing in the catch to bend the values toward your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `TryParse` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) method over exception catching (which can be high overhead if called frequently with invalid values):

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", year, month, day), out date))
{
    // Date was valid.
    // date variable now contains a value.
}
else
{
    // Date is not valid, default to today.
    date = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I feel like TryParse with its out parameter is cognitively heavier and I optimize for my productivity so I use a try/catch and log the exceptions. If there is a recurring problem with the input, I add initial parsing before the object construction. To me, exception handling is about keeping myself from getting mired in premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void setBirthdate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    try
    {
        Birthdate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Birthdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected DateTime CheckDate(String date)
{
  DateTime dt;
 try{
    dt = DateTime.Parse(date);

 }catch(Exception ex){
    dt = DateTime.now();
    // may raise an exception
}
  finally{
      return dt;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Grant Winney's code second part has a bug. The assignation after the IsLeapYear check is swapped. Correct code:

```
        public static bool IsValidYearMonthDay(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && month >= 1 && month <= 12)
        {
            int[] days = DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)
                ? new[] { 0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366 }
                : new[] { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365 };

            if (day >= 1 && day <= days[month] - days[month - 1])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And the test:

```
    [TestCase(2019, 10,21,true)]
    [TestCase(2019, 11, 31, false)] //november doesnt have 31, only 30
    [TestCase(2016, 2, 29, true)] // is leap
    [TestCase(2014, 2, 29, false)] // is nop leap
    public static void ValidateYearMonthDay(int year, int month, int day, bool expectedresult)
    {
        var result = Date.IsValidYearMonthDay(year, month, day);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedresult, result);
    }
```